# Non solubility of a Pell equation

Tags: pell-type-equations

I have this Pell equation
$$x^2-223y^2=-3$$
I know there aren't solutions over the integers. How can i prove it without using things like continuous fractions? I tried reducing modulo some prime but I don't find anything

Comment: Congruences won't work, since one can always reduce the solutions $P = [14/3,1/3]$ or $Q = [-23/11,2/11]$. Note that there does exist a solution to $a^2 - 223 b^2 = 1$ given by $224^2 - 223 \cdot 15^2 = 1$. Let $\epsilon = 224 + 15 \sqrt{223} \sim 447.99\ldots$ be the corresponding fundamental unit.

Comment: The basic idea to show a solution doesn't exist is to give a bound on the "smallest" such solution. Let $\alpha = x + \sqrt{223} y$ and $\beta = x - \sqrt{223} y$. Since their product has absolute value $3$, we may assume that $|\alpha| > \sqrt{3}$. We may even assume that $x$ and $y$ are positive. Consider the smallest such $\alpha$. I claim that $|\alpha| \le \sqrt{3} \epsilon = \sqrt{3}(224 + 15 \sqrt{223}) \sim 775.95\ldots$. The point is that we can replace any bigger solution by $\alpha/\epsilon$ which still has norm $-3$ and is at least $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Once we deduce that $|x + y \sqrt{223}| < 775.95\ldots$, we quickly deduce that $y$ is at most $52$ (being slighly more clever we could also deduce that $y$ is at most $26$), and then we are reduced to checking finitely many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine someone will show up and give a proof consistent with the book you are reading, Marcus I think.

In the meanwhile, as indefinite binary quadratic forms, there are six classes, where (4.) and (5.) are "opposites" and are in the principal genus. These are mapped to an ideal class group of three elements; a form and the form mutiplied by $-1$ are sent to the same ideal.

```
    1.             1          28         -27   cycle length             4
    2.            -1          28          27   cycle length             4
    3.             3          28          -9   cycle length             6
    4.            -3          28           9   cycle length             6
    5.             9          28          -3   cycle length             6
    6.            -9          28           3   cycle length             6

  form class number is   6
```

The principal class has this Lagrange cycle of reduced forms

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle  1 28 -27

  0  form              1          28         -27


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   1 28 -27   delta  -1     ambiguous  
1  form   -27 26 2   delta  13
2  form   2 26 -27   delta  -1     ambiguous  
3  form   -27 28 1   delta  28
4  form   1 28 -27


  form   1 x^2  + 28 x y  -27 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 892 dSqrt 29  M_Ratio  841
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
14  405
15  434
=========================================
```

and does (primitively) represent $-27$ but not $-3.$  We know that $-3$ must be represented by either one or two forms of the discriminant (if two, opposite classes)

and here one is:

---

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle  -3 28 9 

  0  form             -3          28           9


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   -3 28 9   delta  3
1  form   9 26 -6   delta  -4
2  form   -6 22 17   delta  1
3  form   17 12 -11   delta  -1
4  form   -11 10 18   delta  1
5  form   18 26 -3   delta  -9
6  form   -3 28 9


  form   -3 x^2  + 28 x y  9 y^2 

minimum was   3rep   x = 1   y = 0 disc 892 dSqrt 29  M_Ratio  93.44444
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-14  135
45  -434
=========================================
```

[image]